# Adapt a differently pin-interspaced chip to be used with an Arduino

Tags: pins

Happy new year to everyone!

This is how my chip looks like:

[image]

Those numbers are millimeters. Both the pin spacing and pin width are different from what Arduino uses.

Is there any quick (or less quick) and reliable way to connect this chip to an Arduino Uno ?

Comment: It is not clear what you intend to do, but why not simply use wires and soldering?

Comment: @jfpoilpret Based on my tools, ability and the scheme above I would think I could not do it. The pin rows are too tightly spaced.

Comment: I'd use some solid copper wire, similar to shown in this video https://youtu.be/5iIcGaf7qPA?t=411 (6:51)

Comment: Wire wrap is an old technology, that may work best on the intended long square pins, but it will work on shorter headers like this too, and you can usually fit the tool between 2mm pins as well as the intended 2.54 mm ones.  It can thus be a handy semi-permanent way to make these connections without getting out the soldering iron (or getting solder on pins you may want to repurpose later), and you can always solder it later as well to overcome any long-term reliability questions from using wrapping on the wrong shape of pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is to buy a pre-made ribbon cable with 2mm pitch (7x2) IDC connector on it.

Solder the free end (or cut the second connector off and strip it if you have a two-ended cable) and solder it to strip-board on which you have already soldered a 14-pin header for breadboard use.

- [An example of the cable I mean.](http://uk.farnell.com/samtec/tcsd-07-s-06-00-01/cable-assembly-idc-14way-6-grey/dp/2493377)

Comment: this inspired me to go through the junk heap of cables and I have found an old parallel cable that I hacked for my purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Adapters from 2mm to 2.54mm (0.1") spacing exist.

Here is
[an example](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1919) and [another example](http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=3800083).

Alternatively you could make up a little PCB or, as suggested by @jfpoilpret, solder wires on.

A further option is to cut a piece of stripboard, score down the middle to break the tracks, stick your chip on, and run wires from the 2mm-spaced pins to the 2.54mm-spaced pins.  Off-cut resistor legs work fairly well, in my experience.  Here's one I made (fairly clumsily) earlier.  Your soldering skill may be better than mine. [image: Here's one I made earlier].

Comment: Thanks MArk; two problems with those adapters -first I would not want to wait for them a couple of weeks until they eventually reach me and they can only do one row of pins whereas my chip got 14 pins on two rows (7 + 7). Could you expand on making my own PCB ? Is that fast ? What do I nee for that ?

Comment: Clarified that there are two links in my answer. The wires would do the trick, or you could use two of the boards, one on each side.  Making your own PCB would be time-consuming and fairly difficult to do well (drilling it particularly, in my opinion and for my level of skill), and you'll have to wait just as long for the stuff to do it.  Google or YouTube will tell you how to do it, I'm sure.